# Data from MySQL not showing while building dynamic menu in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, loops, menu

I'm building a dynamic menu using PHP and MySQL but results are not showing:

The website structure is built below:

```
<div id="container">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="index.php">home</a></li>                 
            <li>
                <a href="#" id="destinations">destinations &triangledown;</a>

                <div id="subMenu">   

                <div class="nav-column">                         
                    <a href="#" class="continente">Europe</a>                           
                </div>

                <div class="nav-column" >                       
                    <a href="#" id="Africa">Africa</a>                         
                </div>      

                <div class="nav-column" >                      
                    <a href="#" id="Asia">Asia</a>                          
                </div>   

                 <div class="nav-column">                      
                     <a href="#" id="Oceania">Oceania</a>                          
                </div> 

                 <div class="nav-column">                      
                     <a href="#" id="North">North America</a>                          
                </div>   

                <div class="nav-column">                      
                    <a href="#" id="South">South America</a>                          
                </div>                    
                </div>                    
            </li>                
            <li><a href="#about">about</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
        </ul>         
</div>
```

Then i have a continents DB and then another DB with countries, which connect to their respective continent.

So, in the subMenu div, i want to call each continent and then in each div cnt_submenu_, loop through a unordered list of 9 results and then show another  with the same number of results and so on until all the countries with the same id reaches the end.

Here is what i'm trying to do with the PHP code below:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
?>

<div id="container">
     <ul class="nav">
         <li><a href="index.php">home</a></li>                 
         <li><a href="#" id="destinations">destinations</a>
             <div id="subMenu">                   
             <?php 
                $servername = "localhost:3306";
                $username = "root";
                $password = "";
                $dbname = "site_comboios";

               //Open DB connection
      $mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

     //check connection
     if($mysqli->connect_errno) {
     echo 'Error connecting to database';
     exit();
           }

     //show sub-menu
     $query = "SELECT * FROM continentes ORDER BY id";
     $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);  
     $div = 0;    
     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
          $país = $row['continente'];
          echo "<div class='nav-column'><a href='#' class='continente'  data-id='cnt_submenu'>" .($país). "</a></div> ";  </div> ";
        }
     ?>                      

</div>                    
</li>                
<li><a href="#about">about</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
        </ul>         
 </div>  


<div id="cnt_submenu_"   class="submenu_continente active">    

<?php
    //retrieve european countries from DB and open <ul> with 9 results
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost:3306","root","","site_comboios");
    $sql_countries = "SELECT * FROM countries ORDER BY id WHERE      id_continentes = 1" ;
    $res_countries = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_countries);

if($res_countries > 0) { 
     while ($row_countries = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res_countries)) {
        $país = $row_countries['id_continente'];
        echo "<ul><li><a href='#'>". $país ."";
}

} else if ($res_countries == 9) {
       echo '</li></ul>';
}
?>
<span class="close">x</span>
</div>
```

Thanks for pointing me out in the right direction.

*Edited* I'm trying to show through 9 results onto a , close it and open another  with 9 results until the end of the countries with id = 1.
Added the jquery to open each continent div below but i'm not doing it right:

```
//Open and close each div with country list 
$('.continente').hover(function(){ 
      menuHide('submenu_continente' . $(this).data("id")  );
$('#cnt_submenu_' . $(this).data("id") ).show(); 
      },function(){
$('#cnt_submenu_' . $(this).data("id")).mouseleave( function() {
      $(this).hide();    
      });
});
```

Comment: You're not closing your `<a>` in your echo. Does it work if you add a `>` after `id='cnt_'`?

Comment: You're right. now the submenu displays. Now, i still can't display the sub-submenu containing the countries. I'm trying to show a div with the respective country list inside but it still doesn't display. I've edited the code and added the jQuery code.